# The meaning of "over" used with here

Tags: word-meaning

1) What are you doing here?
2) What are you doing over here?

When I bump into a friend, are the two questions above all correct? If so, does "over" here imply that friend comes from another place to here?

Comment: Used with "here" the preposition "over" is *directional*.  One can't ***be*** "over here" (or do, or be doing), one can only ***come*** "over here".

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  I think the directionality is in my imagination...  I'll prepare an answer if I can.

Comment: @VictorBazarov: Rubbish! [***I'm over here**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+over+here%22)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comprehension is correct.  The meaning of "over here" when talking of position or direction implies that the origin of the supposed transition is ***somewhat remote*** with respect to "***here***".

> (*looking around and not seeing*) "Where are you?" -- "I'm **over here**!"
>   (*from a table in the far corner*) "Come **over here**, private!"

So, when you ask your friend

> "What are you doing **over here**?"

, you likely mean

> "What are you doing **here**, *so far away from where I expected you to be*?"

or

> "What are you doing **here**, *all the way from {the other place}*?"

Such additional meaning is of course absent from the simple "What are you doing here?"

Comment: + you can use 'over' by itself too with the same meaning- (in, at, to, toward etc) a location away in relation to another location: We went over to say hi; They sent over more troops before long; we handed over our money; We can drive over- or even walk- it's not far etc